# Threading in a PyQt application: Use Qt threads or Python threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm writing a GUI application that regularly retrieves data through a web connection. Since this retrieval takes a while, this causes the UI to be unresponsive during the retrieval process (it cannot be split into smaller parts). This is why I'd like to outsource the web connection to a separate worker thread.

[Yes, I know, now I have [two problems](http://codemines.blogspot.com/2006/08/now-they-have-two-problems.html).]

Anyway, the application uses PyQt4, so I'd like to know what the better choice is: Use Qt's threads or use the Python `threading` module? What are advantages / disadvantages of each? Or do you have a totally different suggestion?

**Edit (re bounty):** While the solution in my particular case will probably be using a non-blocking network request like [Jeff Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595649/threading-in-a-pyqt-application-use-qt-threads-or-python-threads/1595690#1595690) and [Lukáš Lalinský](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595649/threading-in-a-pyqt-application-use-qt-threads-or-python-threads/1595754#1595754) suggested (so basically leaving the concurrency problems to the networking implementation), I'd still like a more in-depth answer to the general question:

What are advantages and disadvantages of using PyQt4's (i.e. Qt's) threads over native Python threads (from the `threading` module)?

---

**Edit 2:** Thanks all for you answers. Although there's no 100% agreement, there seems to be widespread consensus that the answer is "use Qt", since the advantage of that is integration with the rest of the library, while causing no real disadvantages.

For anyone looking to choose between the two threading implementations, I highly recommend they read all the answers provided here, including the PyQt mailing list thread that [abbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595649/threading-in-a-pyqt-application-use-qt-threads-or-python-threads/1645666#1645666) links to.

There were several answers I considered for the bounty; in the end I chose abbot's for the very relevant external reference; it was, however, a close call.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This was [discussed](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg16050.html) not too long ago in PyQt mailing list. Quoting Giovanni Bajo's [comments](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg16052.html) on the subject:

> It's mostly the same. The main difference is that QThreads are better
>   integrated with Qt (asynchrnous signals/slots, event loop, etc.).
>   Also, you can't use Qt from a Python thread (you can't for instance
>   post event to the main thread through QApplication.postEvent): you
>   need a QThread for that to work.
>
> A general rule of thumb might be to use QThreads if you're going to interact somehow with Qt, and use Python threads otherwise.

And some earlier comment on this subject from PyQt's author: "they are both wrappers around the same native thread implementations". And both implementations use GIL in the same way.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you should be using the blockquote button to clearly show where you are in fact not summarizing but quoting Giovanni Bajo from the mailing list :)

Comment: I wonder why you cannot post events to the main thread through QApplication.postEvent() and need a QThread for that? I think I have seen people doing it and it worked.

Comment: I've called `QCoreApplication.postEvent` from a Python thread at a rate of 100 times per second, in an application that runs cross-platform and has been tested for 1000's of hours. I have never seen any problems from that. I think it's fine as long as the destination object is located in the MainThread or a QThread. I also wrapped it up in a nice library, see [qtutils](http://qtutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Given the highly up-voted nature of this question and answer, I think it's worth pointing out a [recent SO answer by ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802578/1994235) which elaborates on the conditions in which it is safe to use certain Qt methods from Python threads. This tallies with the observed behaviour that has been seen by myself and @Trilarion.

Answer (score 39):

Python's threads will be simpler and safer, and since it is for an I/O-based application, they are able to bypass the GIL. That said, have you considered non-blocking I/O using Twisted or non-blocking sockets/select?

**EDIT: more on threads**

**Python threads**

Python's threads are system threads. However, Python uses a global interpreter lock (GIL) to ensure that the interpreter is only ever executing a certain size block of byte-code instructions at a time. Luckily, Python releases the GIL during input/output operations, making threads useful for simulating non-blocking I/O.

**Important caveat:** This can be misleading, since the number of byte-code instructions does *not* correspond to the number of lines in a program. Even a single assignment may not be atomic in Python, so a mutex lock is necessary for *any* block of code that must be executed atomically, even with the GIL.

**QT threads**

When Python hands off control to a 3rd party compiled module, it releases the GIL. It becomes the responsibility of the module to ensure atomicity where required. When control is passed back, Python will use the GIL. This can make using 3rd party libraries in conjunction with threads confusing. It is even more difficult to use an external threading library because it adds uncertainty as to where and when control is in the hands of the module vs the interpreter.

QT threads operate with the GIL released. QT threads are able to execute QT library code (and other compiled module code that does not acquire the GIL) concurrently. However, the Python code executed within the context of a QT thread *still* acquires the GIL, and now you have to manage *two* sets of logic for locking your code.

In the end, both QT threads and Python threads are wrappers around system threads. Python threads are marginally safer to use, since those parts that are not written in Python (implicitly using the GIL) use the GIL in any case (although the caveat above still applies.)

**Non-blocking I/O**

Threads add extraordinarily complexity to your application. Especially when dealing with the already complex interaction between the Python interpreter and compiled module code. While many find event-based programming difficult to follow, event-based, non-blocking I/O is often much less difficult to reason about than threads.

With asynchronous I/O, you can always be sure that, for each open descriptor, the path of execution is consistent and orderly. There are, obviously, issues that must be addressed, such as what to do when code depending on one open channel further depends on the results of code to be called when another open channel returns data.

One nice solution for event-based, non-blocking I/O is the new [Diesel](http://dieselweb.org/) library. It is restricted to Linux at the moment, but it is extraordinarily fast and quite elegant.

It is also worth your time to learn [pyevent](http://code.google.com/p/pyevent/), a wrapper around the wonderful libevent library, which provides a basic framework for event-based programming using the fastest available method for your system (determined at compile time).

Comment: Re Twisted etc.: I use a third party library that does the actual networking stuff; I'd like to avoid patching around in it. But I'll still look into that, thanks.

Comment: `QThread`s are of course also able to bypass the GIL for operations implemented in C/C++.

Comment: ...which is not an issue when using threads for non-blocking I/O, which releases the GIL.

Comment: I don't know if it actually bypasses the GIL, rather, since you're not doing processor intensive work (just handing off to the kernel for network IO) you won't be significantly constrained by the GIL...its just there doing its job and not bothering you.

Comment: Nothing actually bypasses the GIL. But Python releases the GIL during I/O operations. Python also releases the GIL when 'handing off' to compiled modules, which are responsible for acquiring/releasing the GIL themselves.

Comment: The update is just wrong. Python code runs exactly the same way in a Python thread than in a QThread. You acquite the GIL when you run Python code (and then Python manages the execution between threads), you release it when you run C++ code. There is no difference at all.

Comment: Except for internal management of the threads, and locking therein, as well as managing atomicity of statements. Like my update said, both use system threads when all is said and done.

Comment: No, the point is that no matter how you create the thread, the Python interpreter doesn't care. All it cares about is that it can acquire the GIL and after X instructions it can release/reacquire it. You can for example use ctypes to create a callback from a C library, that will be called in a separate thread, and the code will work fine without even knowing it's a different thread. There is really nothing special about the thread module.

Comment: How is that contradicting the answer? Python code runs under the GIL. Compiled QT library code does not. The difficulty I bring up is actually knowing *when* control passes between the two, especially when you have a mix of libraries, which can create bottlenecks in unexpected places.

Comment: You were saying how QThread is different regarding locking and how "you have to manage two sets of logic for locking your code". What I'm saying is that it isn't different at all. I can use ctypes and pthread_create to start the thread, and it will work exactly the same way. Python code simply doesn't have to care about the GIL.

Comment: I meant that QT has its own locking primitives and its own internal data management which must be locked, so now you are contending with two sets of locks.

And yes, python code *does* have to worry about the GIL. The GIL operates over byte-code instructions, not Python expressions. Even assignment is not atomic in Python.

Answer (score 22):

The advantage of `QThread` is that it's integrated with the rest of the Qt library. That is, thread-aware methods in Qt will need to know in which thread they run, and to move objects between threads, you will need to use `QThread`. Another useful feature is running your own event loop in a thread.

If you are accessing a HTTP server, you should consider `QNetworkAccessManager`.

Comment: Apart from what I commented on Jeff Ober's answer, `QNetworkAccessManager` looks promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I asked myself the same question when I was working to [PyTalk](http://pytalk.trunat.fr/).

If you are using Qt, you need to use `QThread` to be able to use the Qt framework and expecially the signal/slot system.

With the signal/slot engine, you will be able to talk from a thread to another and with every part of your project.

Moreover, there is not very performance question about this choice since both are a C++ bindings.

Here is my experience of PyQt and thread.

I encourage you to use `QThread`.

Answer (score 9):

Jeff has some good points.  Only one main thread can do any GUI updates.  If you do need to update the GUI from within the thread, Qt-4's [queued connection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect-2) signals make it easy to send data across threads and will automatically be invoked if you're using QThread; I'm not sure if they will be if you're using Python threads, although it's easy to add a parameter to `connect()`.

Answer (score 5):

I can't really recommend either, but I can try describing differences between CPython and Qt threads.

First of all, CPython threads do not run concurrently, at least not Python code. Yes, they do create system threads for each Python thread, however only the thread currently holding Global Interpreter Lock is allowed to run (C extensions and FFI code might bypass it, but Python bytecode is not executed while thread doesn't hold GIL).

On the other hand, we have Qt threads, which are basically common layer over system threads, don't have Global Interpreter Lock, and thus are capable of running concurrently. I'm not sure how PyQt deals with it, however unless your Qt threads call Python code, they should be able to run concurrently (bar various extra locks that might be implemented in various structures).

For extra fine-tuning, you can modify the amount of bytecode instructions that are interpreted before switching ownership of GIL - lower values mean more context switching (and possibly higher responsiveness) but lower performance per individual thread (context switches have their cost - if you try switching every few instructions it doesn't help speed.)

Hope it helps with your problems :)

Comment: It's important to note here: PyQt QThreads *do take the Global Interpreter Lock*.  _All_ Python code locks the GIL, and any QThreads you run in PyQt will be running Python code.  (If they don't you aren't actually using the "Py" part of PyQt :).  If you choose to defer from that Python code into an external C library the GIL will be released, but that's true regardless of whether you use a Python thread or a Qt thread.

Comment: That was actually what I tried to convey, that all Python code takes the lock, but it doesn't matter for C/C++ code running in separate thread

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the exact differences between Python and PyQt threads, but I've been doing what you're attempting to do using `QThread`, `QNetworkAcessManager` and making sure to call `QApplication.processEvents()` while the thread is alive.  If GUI responsiveness is really the issue you're trying to solve, [the later](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) will help.

Comment: `QNetworkAcessManager` doesn't require a thread or `processEvents`. It uses asynchronous IO operations.

Comment: Oops...yeah, I'm using a combination of `QNetworkAcessManager` and `httplib2`.  My async code uses `httplib2`.