# time.sleep() required to keep QThread responsive?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, qthread, blit

First, I am new to Python.  I am a long-time MatLab user (engineer, not computer scientist) and I am beginning the process of attempting to work Python, NumPy, SciPy, etc. into my workflow.  So, please excuse my obvious ignorance of what is a wonderful programming language!

As my first endeavor, I decided to build an application to interact with a sensor that I am developing.  The sensor has microsecond resolution (data from 512 high and 512 low energy "pixels" every 500 microseconds), but the I/O will be blocking.  Since I will continually poll the device, I know threading will be important to keep the GUI responsive (the GUI will ultimately also integrate serial communication with another device, and have an image processing subroutine that operates on the sensor data).  I created a threaded instance of MatPlotLib to plot these "real-time" data from the sensor.  Though I've built the module that communicates with the sensor independently and verified I know how to do that in Python, I am starting here simply with a "simulation" of the data by generating 512 random numbers between 8 and 12 for the low energy "pixels", and 512 random numbers between 90 and 110 for the high energy "pixels".  That is what is threaded.  Working from many examples here, I also learned to use blitting to get a fast enough screen update with MatPlotLib -- BUT, the problem is that unless I use put the threaded process to sleep for 20ms using `time.sleep(0.02)`, the GUI is unresponsive.  This can be verified because the interactive X,Y data point feedback from MatPlotLib doesn't work and the 'STOP' button cannot be used to interrupt the process.  Anything longer than `time.sleep(0.02)` makes the GUI operated even smoother, but at the expense of "data rate".  Anything slower than `time.sleep(0.02)` makes the GUI unresponsive.  I'm not sure I understand why.  I was going to go off and try to use GUIqwt instead, but thought I would ask here before abandoning MatPlotLib since I'm not sure that is even the problem.  I am concerned that putting the thread to sleep for 20ms will mean that I miss at least 40 potential lines of data from the sensor array (40 lines * 500us/line = 20ms).

Here is the current code:

```
import time, random, sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class ApplicationWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.thread = Worker()

        self.create_main_frame()
        self.create_status_bar()

        self.connect(self.thread, SIGNAL("finished()"), self.update_UI)
        self.connect(self.thread, SIGNAL("terminated()"), self.update_UI)       
        self.connect(self.startButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.start_acquisition)       
        self.connect(self.stopButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.stop_acquisition)
        self.thread.pixel_list.connect(self.update_figure)

    def create_main_frame(self):
        self.main_frame = QWidget()

        self.dpi = 100
        self.width = 10
        self.height = 8
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(self.width, self.height), dpi=self.dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)               
        self.axes.axis((0,512,0,120))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self.main_frame)
        self.canvas.updateGeometry()    
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.background = None

        self.lE_line, = self.axes.plot(range(512), [0 for i in xrange(512)], animated=True)
        self.hE_line, = self.axes.plot(range(512), [0 for i in xrange(512)], animated=True)          

        self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.main_frame)

        self.startButton = QPushButton(self.tr("&Start"))
        self.stopButton = QPushButton(self.tr("&Stop"))

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton, 2, 0)       
        layout.addWidget(self.stopButton, 2, 1)

        self.main_frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("XRTdev Interface"))

    def create_status_bar(self):
        self.status_text = QLabel("I am a status bar.  I need a status to show!")
        self.statusBar().addWidget(self.status_text, 1)

    def start_acquisition(self):
        self.thread.exiting = False
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.thread.render()

    def stop_acquisition(self):
        self.thread.exiting = True
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.cleanup_UI()

    def update_figure(self, lE, hE):
        if self.background == None:
            self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.lE_line.set_ydata(lE)
        self.hE_line.set_ydata(hE)
        self.axes.draw_artist(self.lE_line)
        self.axes.draw_artist(self.hE_line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.axes.bbox)

    def update_UI(self):
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.cleanup_UI()        

    def cleanup_UI(self):
        self.background = None
        self.axes.clear()        
        self.canvas.draw()

class Worker(QThread):

    pixel_list = pyqtSignal(list, list)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def render(self):
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        # simulate I/O
        n = random.randrange(100,200)
        while not self.exiting and n > 0:
            lE = [random.randrange(5,16) for i in xrange(512)]
            hE = [random.randrange(80,121) for i in xrange(512)]
            self.pixel_list.emit(lE, hE)
            time.sleep(0.02)
            n -= 1

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ApplicationWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Perhaps my problem isn't even with MatPlotLib or PyQT4, but the way I implemented threading.  As I noted, I am new to this and learning.  And, I'm not even sure GUIqwt will address any of these issues -- but I do know I've seen many recommendations here to use something faster than MatPlotLib for "real time" plotting in a GUI.  Thanks for the help on this!

Comment: Your code is working fine and your thread usage is OK. The unresponsiveness without a `sleep` comes from the matplotlib part, namely `update_figure`. It's not _free_ to update/render a plot and it's working on the main thread. If you do that too fast, event loop doesn't get much chance to process events.

Comment: @Avaris  Thanks for the clarification.  Despite the varied use of threading, both you and tcaswell agree that the data generation is too fast for the UI, especially with MatPlotLib.  I will work to downsample the data and possibly implement a lighter-weight plotting toolkit and post back here with the results.

Comment: Another possibility is moving the matplotlib rendering to the thread and getting back a `QImage` that you can show in the GUI. This will be less expensive for the main thread. This is similar to the way matplotlib shows plot using `Qt` backend. [This](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py#L82) might give you an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edited because `QThread` is confusing/confused]

There seems to be two ways to use it, either sub-classing it (as your example and the documentation says) or creating a worker object and then moving it to a thread (See [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/)).  I then get more confused when you mix signal/slots in.  As Avaris says, this change may not be your problem.

I re-worked your `Worker` class as a a sub-class of `QObject` (because this is the style I understand).

A problem is that if you do not put a `sleep` in your fake data system, then you generate all the call backs to the main window in < 1s.  The main thread is then essentially blocked as it clears out the signal queue.  If you set the delay to your specified delay, (0.0005s), then it cranks through generating the data far faster than it can be displayed, which seems to suggest that this may not be suitable for your problem (being pragmatic, you also can't see that fast, and it seems to do ok at 30 - 40 fps).

```
import time, random, sys
#from PySide.QtCore import *
#from PySide.QtGui import *

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    get_data = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)


        self.thread = QtCore.QThread(parent=self)
        self.worker = Worker(parent=None)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.create_main_frame()
        self.create_status_bar()

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_acquisition) 
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_acquisition)
        self.worker.pixel_list.connect(self.update_figure)
        self.worker.done.connect(self.update_UI)

        self.get_data.connect(self.worker.get_data)


        self.thread.start()


    def create_main_frame(self):
        self.main_frame = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.dpi = 100
        self.width = 10
        self.height = 8
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(self.width, self.height), dpi=self.dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)               
        self.axes.axis((0,512,0,120))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self.main_frame)
        self.canvas.updateGeometry()    
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.background = None

        self.lE_line, = self.axes.plot(range(512), [0 for i in xrange(512)], animated=True)
        self.hE_line, = self.axes.plot(range(512), [0 for i in xrange(512)], animated=True)          

        self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.main_frame)

        self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tr("&Start"))
        self.stopButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tr("&Stop"))

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton, 2, 0)       
        layout.addWidget(self.stopButton, 2, 1)

        self.main_frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_frame)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("XRTdev Interface"))

    def create_status_bar(self):
        self.status_text = QtGui.QLabel("I am a status bar.  I need a status to show!")
        self.statusBar().addWidget(self.status_text, 1)

    def start_acquisition(self):
        self.worker.exiting = False
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.get_data.emit()

    def stop_acquisition(self):
        self.worker.exiting = True
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.cleanup_UI()

    def update_figure(self, lE, hE):
        if self.background == None:
            self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.lE_line.set_ydata(lE)
        self.hE_line.set_ydata(hE)
        self.axes.draw_artist(self.lE_line)
        self.axes.draw_artist(self.hE_line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.axes.bbox)

    def update_UI(self):
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.stopButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.cleanup_UI()        

    def cleanup_UI(self):
        self.background = None
        self.axes.clear()        
        self.canvas.draw()

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    pixel_list = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list, list)
    done = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = True

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def get_data(self):
        # simulate I/O
        print 'data_start'
        n = random.randrange(100,200)
        while not self.exiting and n > 0:
            lE = [random.randrange(5,16) for i in xrange(512)]
            hE = [random.randrange(80,121) for i in xrange(512)]
            self.pixel_list.emit(lE, hE)
            time.sleep(0.05)
            n -= 1
        print 'n: ', n
        self.done.emit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and for focusing me on the actual problem.  The blog post seems to tackle the issue from a C++ perspective.  I'll start searching, but any links to help me work this out from a Python/PyQT perspective will help tremendously!

Comment: @jjwebster the pyQt wrappers are _very_ thin.  Any of the c++ examples or discussion still apply, you just have to do the syntax change in your head.

Comment: by very thin, I mean all of the pyqt object are really proxy objects for the underlying c++ object and almost all of the wrapper generation is automated.  I primarily reference the c++ documentation, rather than the wrapper documentation and have only found a few divergences.

Comment: Indeed, but given my (near zero) knowledge of C++ and (limited) knowledge of Python, "changing the syntax in my head" is easier said than done!  It's helpful to see it implemented in Python and I can adapt from there.

Comment: In fact, I based my threading on [this](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Threading,_Signals_and_Slots) example, which was in [another Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773716/pyqt4-qthread-and-opening-big-files-without-freezing-the-gui) that received several up-votes... but which apparently implements QThread incorrectly?

Comment: ah, sorry for assuming too much ;)  Give me a few more minutes, and I will have a better answer for you.

Comment: @tcaswell: That's not right. `Worker` instance will be in the main thread (just like your `self.thread`) but the `run` method will run in the other thread. Subclassing `QThread` is not _inherently_ wrong.