# Pyplot animation not updating continuously

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to display the frames captured by a CCD camera in real-time using pyplot animation. I wrote a short python script just to test this out, and while it works, it does so erratically. It will quickly update a dozen or so animation frames, then pause for a second, then update again, then pause again, and so on. I'd like to just have it update the plot continuously and smoothly, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I know it isn't the part where it makes a call to the camera's frame buffer; I tested out just calling that in a loop and it never slowed down, so I think it's somewhere in the actual processing of the animation frames.

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import Pixis100
import time

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    

# Create ccd object
ccd = Pixis100.device()
ccd.snapshot()
ccd.focusStart()
# focusStart() tells the camera to start putting captured frames into the buffer

line, = ax.plot(ccd.getFrame()[:,2:].sum(axis=0)[::-1],'b-')
# getFrame() makes a call to the CCD frame buffer and retrieves the most recent frame

# animation function
def update(data):    
    line.set_ydata(data)
    return line,

def data_gen():
    while True: yield ccd.getFrame()[:,2:].sum(axis=0)[::-1]

# call the animator
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen,interval=10,blit=True)

plt.show()
ccd.focusStop()
# focusStop() just tells the camera to stop capturing frames
```

For reference, ccd.getFrame()[:,2:].sum(axis=0)[::-1] returns a 1x1338 array of integers. I wouldn't think this would be too much for the animation to handle at one time.

Comment: does it run better if you increase the interval?  I would point out 10ms is 100fps.  I suspect the culprit here is the gui-frame work you are using not being able to re-draw the canvas at that rate.  It as also not clear if you have a question or are just whining.

Comment: Changing the interval doesn't help. My question is what would cause the plot to update erratically, as I described; if it's an issue of pyplot and a different plotting library would work better, or if there's something within pyplot I can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `animation`, the following works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

import time

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    
ax.set_xlim([0, 2 *np.pi])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])

th = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)

line, = ax.plot([],[],'b-', animated=True)
line.set_xdata(th)
# getFrame() makes a call to the CCD frame buffer and retrieves the most recent frame

# animation function
def update(data):    
    line.set_ydata(data)

    return line,

def data_gen():
    t = 0
    while True:
        t +=1
        yield np.sin(th + t * np.pi/100)

# call the animator
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, data_gen, interval=10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The choppyness may come from either your frame grabber, the computation your are doing on it, or issues with the gui getting enough time on the main thread to re-draw.  See [time.sleep() required to keep QThread responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665636/time-sleep-required-to-keep-qthread-responsive/14666811#14666811)