# Can you plot live data in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm reading data from a socket in one thread and would like to plot and update the plot as new data arrives. I coded up a small prototype to simulate things but it doesn't work:

```
import pylab
import time
import threading
import random

data = []

# This just simulates reading from a socket.
def data_listener():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        data.append(random.random())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=data_listener)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    pylab.figure()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        pylab.plot(data)
        pylab.show() # This blocks :(
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665636/time-sleep-required-to-keep-qthread-responsive

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955869/why-is-plotting-with-matplotlib-so-slow/8956211#8956211

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib/15724978#15724978

Comment: Also look into the `animation` module which will automate the timers and take care of blitting for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import threading
import random

data = []

# This just simulates reading from a socket.
def data_listener():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        data.append(random.random())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=data_listener)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    #
    # initialize figure
    plt.figure() 
    ln, = plt.plot([])
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    while True:
        plt.pause(1)
        ln.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
        ln.set_ydata(data)
        plt.draw()
```

If you want to go really fast, you should look into blitting.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to display streaming graph. I tried this piece of code and got "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'figure'". Then I tried to "import matplotlib.pylab as plt" instead of pylab and got "RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length". Something wrong with my environment? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks. This one is better...just add ")" at ln.set_xdata(range(len(data))

Comment: Turning on interactive mode would cause the figure not to show when I run the script from the command line. This answer using `matplotlib.animation` worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib

Comment: This code just shows a blank plot on my laptop. Brand new installation of Anaconda 3

Answer (score -1):

`f.show()` does not block, and you can use `draw` to update the figure.

```
f = pylab.figure()
f.show()
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    pylab.plot(data)
    pylab.draw()
```