# matplotlib update data in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I'm new in `matplotlib`.
I want to update a data in an endless while loop in a different thread
in addition to updating the plot in the    pyplot.show    method.
I tried using the threading import but it isn't working
well together with `pyplot.show` method.
I know I can use `pyplot.ion` and it works fine with the threads.
The problem with `pyplot.ion` is that it is not efficient.
Is there any way that i could use `pyplot.show` instead?

To make myself clear, I don't want the solution:

```
    pyplot.ion()
    ....
    while True:
    ....
        pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found `gobject.idle_add()` and `gobject.threads_init()` to be very useful. It was almost exactly what I needed.
I also found these resources useful:
[Can you plot live data in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791722/can-you-plot-live-data-in-matplotlib)
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but you could try to use `pyplot.draw()`instead of `pyplot.show()`.  If you already have used `show()` once, will it update the plot? `draw()` should update the plot though.

I do not know how you plot the data, but assuming that the data-set you're plotting is of the same size every time one trick to speed things up is to use `set_data()`, if you the first time you plot store the line-artist as

```
x, y = generate_data_function()
line, = pyplot.plot(x, y)
pyplot.show()

while True:
    x, y = generate_data_function()
    line.set_data(x, y)
    pyplot.draw()
```

Hope it helps! As I said, I'm not completely sure if it really solves your problem but it could be worth trying at least.

Comment: Umm, yes this works, but I have already known about this solution " I know I can use pyplot.ion and it works fine with the threads". But I used `pyplot.ion` instead of `pyplot.show`. I think `pyplot.show` won't work, as it will stop at that line.