# Plotting of streaming data in matplotlib: The need for speed

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, streaming, accelerometer

I am streaming accelerometer data from my android phone and have successfully built a live plot using matplotlib. I am using the comma operator to dynamically update the plot but I am wondering if there is a more elegant/pythonic way to do it. To execute the code below you must use the app [Sensorstream IMU+GPS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartphone-imu/). The code below will grab the accelerometer values and plot them live. I based the plotting on [Can you plot live data in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791722/can-you-plot-live-data-in-matplotlib). Like I said it works but the code is clumsy. Even with speedups mentioned in the [matplotlib documentation](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Animations.html?highlight=blit) I am running at about 25 FPS. The technique, if I only use a simple plot can get up to about 90 FPS. It can be shown that you can achieve ~200 FPS of faster here [why is plotting with Matplotlib so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955869/why-is-plotting-with-matplotlib-so-slow). I cannot find my bottleneck. So, is there a more elegant way to code up all the subplots? Second, can I speed up the plotting?

```
import socket, traceback
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter,iirfilter,savgol_filter
import math
import pylab
from pylab import *
import time
import numpy as np


host = ''
port = 5555
 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind((host, port))

# lists for plotting
Ax = [0.0] * 50
Ay = [0.0] * 50
Az = [0.0] * 50
G  = [0.0] * 50
x = [i for i in range(len(Ax))]
 
#used for debugging
 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))

# raw data
ax = plt.subplot("311")
ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_title("Raw acceleration data")
ax.set_ylabel("g$/m^2$",fontsize=18)
ax.hold(True)

line  = ax.plot(Ax,label='Acc x')[0]
line2 = ax.plot(Ay,label='Acc y')[0]
line3 = ax.plot(Az,label='Acc z')[0]

# filtered data
ax2 = plt.subplot("312")
ax2.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax2.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax2.set_title(" acceleration data")
ax2.set_ylabel("g$/m^2$",fontsize=18)
ax2.hold(True)

f_line  = ax2.plot(Ax,label='Acc x')[0]
f_line2 = ax2.plot(Ay,label='Acc y')[0]
f_line3 = ax2.plot(Az,label='Acc z')[0]

# tilt angle plot
ax3 = plt.subplot("313")
ax3.set_ylim([-180,180])
ax3.set_title("Tilt Angles")
ax3.set_ylabel("degrees",fontsize=18)
t_line = ax3.plot(G)[0]

fig.suptitle('Three-axis accelerometer streamed from Sensorstream',fontsize=18)
plt.show(False)
plt.draw()

# cache the background
background = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)

count = 0 
print("Success binding")
while 1:
    # time it
    tstart = time.time()
    message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
    messageString = message.decode("utf-8")
    Acc = messageString.split(',')[2:5]
    Acc = [float(Acc[i])/10.0 for i in range(3)]
    
    # appending and deleting is order 10e-5 sec
    Ax.append(Acc[0])
    del Ax[0]
    Ay.append(Acc[1])
    del Ay[0]
    Az.append(Acc[2])
    del Az[0]
    G.append(np.sqrt(Ax[-1]**2 + Ay[-1]**2 + Az[-1]**2))
    del G[0]
    
    # filter
    acc_x_savgol = savgol_filter(Ax, window_length=5, polyorder=3)
    acc_y_savgol = savgol_filter(Ay, window_length=5, polyorder=3)
    acc_z_savgol = savgol_filter(Az, window_length=5, polyorder=3)
    
    tilt_angles = []
    for i,val in enumerate(G): 
        angle = math.atan2(Ax[i], -1*Ay[i]) * (180 / math.pi)
        if (math.isnan(angle)):
            tilt_angles.append(0)
        else:
            tilt_angles.append(angle)
            
    print(Ax[0],Ay[1],Az[2])   
    
    line.set_xdata(x)
    line.set_ydata(Ax)
    line2.set_xdata(x)
    line2.set_ydata(Ay)
    line3.set_xdata(x)
    line3.set_ydata(Az)
    ax.set_xlim(count, count+50)
    
    f_line.set_xdata(x)
    f_line.set_ydata(acc_x_savgol)
    f_line2.set_xdata(x)
    f_line2.set_ydata(acc_y_savgol)
    f_line3.set_xdata(x)
    f_line3.set_ydata(acc_z_savgol)
    ax2.set_xlim(count, count+50)

    t_line.set_xdata(x)
    t_line.set_ydata(tilt_angles)
    ax3.set_xlim(count, count+50)
    # restore background
    fig.canvas.restore_region(background)

    # redraw just the points
    ax.draw_artist(line)
    ax.draw_artist(line2)
    ax.draw_artist(line3)
    ax2.draw_artist(f_line)
    ax2.draw_artist(f_line2)
    ax2.draw_artist(f_line3)
    ax3.draw_artist(t_line)

    # fill in the axes rectangle
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    
    count+=1
    x = np.arange(count,count+50,1)
    
    # tops out at about 25 fps :|
    print "Total time for 1 plot is: ",(time.time() - tstart)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes) you need to `plot` a subplot before adding a new plot to the current figure. It mentions `plt.figure(x)` is optional, but it is recommended to do so. I would append the following code to plot multiple sub-plots.

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot('''Data''')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot('''Data''')
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but could you be a little more specific on how this answers the questions?

Comment: I meant to say you need to `plot()` the results before `draw()` them. That way the interpreter knows the canvas is filled with sub-plots.