# Update variable from sensor in Widget with Signal and Slot

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt, signals, signals-slots

I have a deployment with the reading of a variable of a sensor an `Arduino`, will from value  obtained in the variable , need to update the value of a `QWT widget`.

Never worked with Signal and Slots, then was unable to implement a solution.

Could help me?, the formation of this concept for the compass widget is updated with the value of Variable `words[2]` in line `print "compass = "+ words[2]`. [sensor.py]

The widget has to be updated the following code, and the value set in this way: `compass.setValue(35.0)`.[compass.py] Here, statically;

How do I connect the value of the variable `words[2]`, in the value of the `compass`, when two different files.

Excuse me for my English.
**compass.py**

```
from PyQt4 import Qt, QtGui, QtCore
import PyQt4.Qwt5 as Qwt

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


def enumList(enum, sentinel):
    return [enum(i) for i in range(sentinel)]

colorGroupList = enumList(
    Qt.QPalette.ColorGroup, Qt.QPalette.NColorGroups)
colorRoleList = enumList(
    Qt.QPalette.ColorRole, Qt.QPalette.NColorRoles)
handList  = enumList(
    Qwt.QwtAnalogClock.Hand, Qwt.QwtAnalogClock.NHands)

class Ui_Form(Qt.QFrame):

    def setupUi(self, Form ):   
        compass = Qwt.QwtCompass()

        palette = compass.palette()
        #Cor Interna Bussola
        palette.setColor(compass.backgroundRole(), Qt.Qt.darkCyan)
        compass.setPalette(palette)

        palette = Qt.QPalette()
        for colorRole in colorRoleList:
            palette.setColor(colorRole, Qt.QColor())
        palette.setColor(
            Qt.QPalette.Base,
            #Alterando uma pouco a cor, mais forte ou mais fraco, depende do valor
            compass.palette().color(compass.backgroundRole()).light(105))
        palette.setColor(
            #Cor de fundo do corculo da agulha
            Qt.QPalette.Foreground,
            palette.color(Qt.QPalette.Base))

        compass.setLineWidth(2)
        compass.setFrameShadow(Qwt.QwtCompass.Raised)
        compass.setScaleTicks(0, 0, 2)

        compass.setScaleOptions( Qwt.QwtDial.ScaleTicks |  Qwt.QwtDial.ScaleLabel | 
            Qwt.QwtDial.ScaleBackbone)
        compass.setLabelMap({0.0: "N",
                                 45.0: "ne",
                                 90.0: "E",
                                 135.0: "se",
                                 180.0: "S",
                                 225.0: "so",
                                 270.0: "O",
                                 315.0: "no"})
        compass.setScale(72,0, 0)

        compass.setNeedle(Qwt.QwtCompassMagnetNeedle(
        Qwt.QwtCompassMagnetNeedle.TriangleStyle,
            Qt.Qt.white,
            Qt.Qt.red))
        compass.setValue(35.0)

        newPalette = compass.palette()

        for colorRole in colorRoleList:
            if palette.color(colorRole).isValid():
                for colorGroup in colorGroupList:
                    newPalette.setColor(
                        colorGroup, colorRole, palette.color(colorRole))

        compass.setPalette(newPalette)

        return compass

class WidgetBussola(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)  

        palette = self.palette()
        #Cor Interna Bussola
        palette.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.Qt.darkCyan)
        self.setPalette(palette)

        #Posicionamento do Widget
        layout = Qt.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.ui.setupUi(1),1,1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1,1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    # BUSSOLA
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    bussola = WidgetBussola()
    bussola.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**sensor.py**

```
from visual import *
import serial
import string
import math

from time import time

grad2rad = 3.141592/180.0

# Check your COM port and baud rate
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3',baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

# Main scene
scene=display(title="9DOF Razor IMU test")
scene.range=(1.2,1.2,1.2)
#scene.forward = (0,-1,-0.25)
scene.forward = (1,0,-0.25)
scene.up=(0,0,1)

# Second scene (Roll, Pitch, Yaw)
scene2 = display(title='9DOF Razor IMU test',x=0, y=0, width=500, height=200,center=(0,0,0), background=(0,0,0))
scene2.range=(1,1,1)
scene.width=500
scene.y=200

scene2.select()
#Roll, Pitch, Yaw
cil_roll = cylinder(pos=(-0.4,0,0),axis=(0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.red)
cil_roll2 = cylinder(pos=(-0.4,0,0),axis=(-0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.red)
cil_pitch = cylinder(pos=(0.1,0,0),axis=(0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.green)
cil_pitch2 = cylinder(pos=(0.1,0,0),axis=(-0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.green)
#cil_course = cylinder(pos=(0.6,0,0),axis=(0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.blue)
#cil_course2 = cylinder(pos=(0.6,0,0),axis=(-0.2,0,0),radius=0.01,color=color.blue)
arrow_course = arrow(pos=(0.6,0,0),color=color.cyan,axis=(-0.2,0,0), shaftwidth=0.02, fixedwidth=1)

#Roll,Pitch,Yaw labels
label(pos=(-0.4,0.3,0),text="Roll",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0.1,0.3,0),text="Pitch",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0.55,0.3,0),text="Yaw",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0.6,0.22,0),text="N",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.6,-0.22,0),text="S",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.38,0,0),text="W",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.82,0,0),text="E",box=0,opacity=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.75,0.15,0),height=7,text="NE",box=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.45,0.15,0),height=7,text="NW",box=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.75,-0.15,0),height=7,text="SE",box=0,color=color.yellow)
label(pos=(0.45,-0.15,0),height=7,text="SW",box=0,color=color.yellow)

L1 = label(pos=(-0.4,0.22,0),text="-",box=0,opacity=0)
L2 = label(pos=(0.1,0.22,0),text="-",box=0,opacity=0)
L3 = label(pos=(0.7,0.3,0),text="-",box=0,opacity=0)

# Main scene objects
scene.select()
# Reference axis (x,y,z)
arrow(color=color.green,axis=(1,0,0), shaftwidth=0.02, fixedwidth=1)
arrow(color=color.green,axis=(0,-1,0), shaftwidth=0.02 , fixedwidth=1)
arrow(color=color.green,axis=(0,0,-1), shaftwidth=0.02, fixedwidth=1)
# labels
label(pos=(0,0,0.8),text="9DOF Razor IMU test",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(1,0,0),text="X",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0,-1,0),text="Y",box=0,opacity=0)
label(pos=(0,0,-1),text="Z",box=0,opacity=0)
# IMU object
platform = box(length=1, height=0.05, width=1, color=color.red)
p_line = box(length=1,height=0.08,width=0.1,color=color.yellow)
plat_arrow = arrow(color=color.green,axis=(1,0,0), shaftwidth=0.06, fixedwidth=1)


f = open("Serial"+str(time())+".txt", 'w')

roll=0
pitch=0
yaw=0
while 1:
    line = ser.readline()
    line = line.replace("!ANG:","")   # Delete "!ANG:"

    f.write(line)                     # Write to the output log file
    words = string.split(line,",")    # Fields split
    if len(words) > 2:
        try:
            roll = float(words[0])*grad2rad
            pitch = float(words[1])*grad2rad
            yaw = float(words[2])*grad2rad
            print "Bussula=" + words[2]

        except:
            print "Invalid line"

        axis=(cos(pitch)*cos(yaw),-cos(pitch)*sin(yaw),sin(pitch)) 
        up=(sin(roll)*sin(yaw)+cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*cos(yaw),sin(roll)*cos(yaw)-cos(roll)*sin(pitch)*sin(yaw),-cos(roll)*cos(pitch))
        platform.axis=axis
        platform.up=up
        platform.length=1.0
        platform.width=0.65
        plat_arrow.axis=axis
        plat_arrow.up=up
        plat_arrow.length=0.8
        p_line.axis=axis
        p_line.up=up
        cil_roll.axis=(0.2*cos(roll),0.2*sin(roll),0)
        cil_roll2.axis=(-0.2*cos(roll),-0.2*sin(roll),0)
        cil_pitch.axis=(0.2*cos(pitch),0.2*sin(pitch),0)
        cil_pitch2.axis=(-0.2*cos(pitch),-0.2*sin(pitch),0)
        arrow_course.axis=(0.2*sin(yaw),0.2*cos(yaw),0)
        L1.text = str(float(words[0]))
        L2.text = str(float(words[1]))
        L3.text = str(float(words[2]))        
ser.close
f.close
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, this can only be achieved through threading. 
In a nutshell, the GUI part (PyQt) runs the main thread, while the processing part (the one that receives values from Arduino) runs in another thread.

Take a look at this page, Paul's posted code. You can implement something similar. 
[PyQT and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842558/pyqt-and-threads)