# Eclipse won't break in threads

Tags: multithreading, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to develop a PyQt application using PyDev. It's using two threads, one for gui and one for network traffic and Eclipse refuse to break on breakpoints set in the network traffic thread, I know it runs because it's throwing exceptions but I can't inspect things which is highly annoying.

Has anybody else experienced similar problems?
Pseudocode:

```
 class NetHelper
     sendLots()

 class Worker(QThread):
     run()
        NetHelper.sendLots()

 class GUIThingie(QDialog):
     handleClick():
         self.worker.start()
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm experiencing the same issue at this moment :-/

Comment: Tobi: I think it's because QThread is based on c++-threads which the PyDev-debugger can't handle, switching to inheritance from normal Thread solved the issue for me.

Comment: How do you switch to inheritance from normal Thread?

Comment: @dutt I tried using Python Threads with PyQt4 and the problems was that Qt does not provide a mechanism for communicating from the worker threads to the GUI thread in a thread-safe way. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595649/threading-in-a-pyqt-application-use-qt-threads-or-python-threads).