# Multi-threaded PyOpenCV display

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, qt, opencv, pyqt

I'm working on a demo that will require me to capture video from a camera and display it in real time (after some processing). I followed the template from [OpenCV's docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html), but implemented the capturing (and processing) in a separate thread. As per [this blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/), separating the capturing and display threads can give a significant performance boost to the display's FPS.

This below code is what I currently have.

```
import cv2
import sys
from threading import Thread
import time


class ThreadedProcessor(Thread):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.init()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.cleanup()

    def init(self):
        self.start()

    def cleanup(self):
        if self.is_alive():
            sys.exit()


class BasicVideoProcessor(ThreadedProcessor):
    def __init__(self, camera=0, size=None, init_timeout=10):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera
        self.size = size
        self.capture = None
        self._frame = None

    def init(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera)
        super().init()

    def cleanup(self):
        self.capture.release()
        super().cleanup()

    def run(self):
        self._wait_for_stream()
        while self.capture.isOpened():
            grabbed, frame = self.capture.read()
            self._frame = frame if grabbed else None

    def _wait_for_stream(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                return
        raise ValueError("Timeout")

    def get_frame(self):
        return self._frame


def display(src, fps=30, title="Display"):
    time_per_frame = 1 / fps

    while not src.is_alive():
        time.sleep(1)

    next_frame_time = time.time()
    while src.is_alive():
        frame = src.get_frame()
        if frame is not None:
            cv2.imshow(title, frame)

        next_frame_time += time_per_frame
        curr_time = time.time()
        if curr_time < next_frame_time and cv2_wait_for_q(int((next_frame_time - curr_time) / 1000)):
            break


# https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html
def cv2_wait_for_q(ms=0):
    return cv2.waitKey(ms) & 0xFF == ord('q')


def main():
    with BasicVideoProcessor() as capture:
        display(capture)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works well enough, and at the moment (without any image processing) is easily able to maintain a 60FPS display, which is good enough given my monitor's refresh rate and my camera's capturing FPS.

However, this code only creates a separate thread for the video capturing. At some point I may need to have several displays active at the same time (e.g. if I wanted to run this on a VR headset, I would need two simultaneous displays), which with the current code would all run in the same thread.

This is why my original code replaced the above `display` and `main` methods with:

```
class Display(ThreadedProcessor):
    def __init__(self, source, fps=30, title="Display"):
        super().__init__()
        self.src = source
        self.fps = fps
        self.time_per_frame = 1 / fps
        self.title = title

    def cleanup(self):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        super().cleanup()

    def run(self):
        while not self.src.is_alive():
            time.sleep(1)
        next_frame_time = time.time()
        while self.src.is_alive():
            frame = self.src.get_frame()
            if frame is not None:  #
                cv2.imshow(self.title, frame)  #

            next_frame_time += self.time_per_frame
            curr_time = time.time()
            if curr_time < next_frame_time and cv2_wait_for_q(int((next_frame_time - curr_time) / 1000)):
                break

def main():
    with BasicVideoProcessor() as capture, Display(capture):
        while not cv2_wait_for_q(1):
            pass
```

This, however, resulted in the following error:

> QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread

The code (unlike the above one) also refuses to terminate with either a Q press (which might be unrelated and caused by the questionable implementation of the `main` method) or Ctrl+C. If I remove the two display lines (marked with `#`), the code runs without errors and does terminate on Ctrl+C, but (obviously) doesn't display anything.

I've tried searching around for the above error and found a few answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11104919/5769814), explaining that PyQt (which is used by `cv2.imshow`) doesn't allow GUI method calls on any thread but the main one.

Is there a way to use a backend that will allow me to implement a threaded display or a way to bypass this issue in PyQt?

Comment: The second one does seem to address this same problem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404349/pyqt-showing-video-stream-from-opencv