# How can you execute code after a widget is created in PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a textbrowser widget and a file.I want to create the textbrowser and then read the file and put the contents in it.I could read the file first and then put it into the textbrowser but if it's a big file it takes some time.Is there a signal emitted when a widget is created?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you wrote the code to create the widget, can't you read the file right after the statement where the widget is created? Or by "created" do you mean when it first becomes visible on the screen?

Comment: When it becomes visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file read is taking long enough to lock up your GUI operations (like rendering widgets) consider loading the file in a separate thread.

Take a look at this post for an example:
[Using a QThread for file loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7614913/2018138)