# PyQt - Refreshing a QStandardItemModel element's text effectively

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

Say I have a QListView and each item in this list is meant to be refreshed with the output of a certain system process (such as some intensive file I/O-ing) which is triggered in a thread (using threading.Thread). The problem I have is that the main window's application freezes shortly after I start a new thread and halts the application. Is there a more effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using `QThread` rather than `threading.Thread`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595649/984421) has a lot of useful discussion about how to use threads correctly in PyQt applications.

Comment: Thank you, it covers my needs.