# Updating a QLCDNumber in PyQt via Background Thread

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread, qlcdnumber

I need to continuously update a QLCDNumber based on data measurements that I'm pulling from a bench-top instrument. I realize that I will have to put this on some sort of daemon thread to run in the background independently.

I have read a bit about QThreads but am not sure if that is the right approach, or if Qt allows for threading that isn't via QThreads.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? I understand what you want to do, but it isn't clear what you need help with.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1595649/1994235. Also, never directly interact with GUI objects from a secondary thread. Yo need to emit a signal (or post an event) back to the main thread and interact with the GUI objects there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to use **Python** or **PyQt** threading modules, **bot of them work** fine, but if you are new to threading I wold recommend to use Qt thread module because it is easier to setup, and If you use Qt Lib. it is easier to implement it in.
Even if this is not a complete answer I hope it helps, PS: try to put some code in the question it may help others to test things out